# Azure DevOps Pipeline Parsing key value pairs from template parameters to create new string variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to pass some key-value pair objects as parameters to my template from the below pipeline code.

**azure-pipeline.yml**

```yaml
jobs:
- template: custom-template.yml
  parameters:
    customProperties:
       - key1: value1
       - key2: value2
```

Below is the pseudo code as part of my template.

**custom-template.yml**

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: customProperties
    type: object
    default: []

jobs:
  - job: MyJob
    steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: "Get all parameter values"
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
             args = (${{ parameters.customProperties }} ) #TODO: loop key value pairs, create variable.
             echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARGS;isoutput=true]args"
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: "Use the parameter values"
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
             echo $(ARGS) # from previous task
```

With the above pipeline `object` input, in my actual template processing, I want to form a string variable in the format as below and use that value in the subsequent steps in my template.

`-Dkey1=value1 -Dkey2=value2`

There are several examples to loop through the parameter values and conditionally include other tasks. But my requirement is to create a variable from the parameter values.